# GADTs, TypeFamilies type inference failure when implementing "mixins"

Tags: haskell, type-inference, gadt

I am trying to create complex data structures with composable logic. That is, the data structure has a generic format (essentially, a record with some fields whose type can change) and some generic functions. Specific structures have specific implementation of the generic functions.

There are two approaches I tried. One is to use the type system (with type classes, type families, functional dependencies etc.). The other is creating my own "vtable" and using GADTs. Both methods fail in a similar way - there seems to be something basic I'm missing here. Or, perhaps, there a better more Haskell-ish way to do this?

Here is the failing "typed" code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

module Typed where

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Lens.Lazy
import Data.Lens.Template

-- Generic Block.
data Block state ports = Block { _blockState :: state, _blockPorts :: ports }

-- For the logic we want to use, we need some state and ports.
data LogicState = LogicState { _field :: Bool }
data LogicPorts incoming outgoing =
  LogicPorts { _input :: incoming, _output :: outgoing }

makeLenses [ ''Block, ''LogicState, ''LogicPorts ]

-- We need to describe how to reach the needed state and ports,
-- and provide a piece of the logic.
class LogicBlock block incoming outgoing | block -> incoming, block -> outgoing where
  logicState :: block ~ Block state ports => Lens state LogicState
  logicPorts :: block ~ Block state ports => Lens ports (LogicPorts incoming outgoing)
  convert :: block ~ Block state ports => incoming -> State block outgoing
  runLogic :: State block outgoing
  runLogic = do
    state <- access $ blockState
    let myField = state ^. logicState ^. field
    if myField
    then do
      ports <- access blockPorts
      let inputMessage = ports ^. logicPorts ^. input
      convert inputMessage
    else
      error "Sorry"

-- My block uses the generic logic, and also maintains additional state
-- and ports.
data MyState = MyState { _myLogicState :: LogicState, _myMoreState :: Bool }
data MyPorts = MyPorts { _myLogicPorts :: LogicPorts Int Bool, _myMorePorts :: Int }

makeLenses [ ''MyState, ''MyPorts ]

type MyBlock = Block MyState MyPorts

instance LogicBlock MyBlock Int Bool where
  logicState = myLogicState
  logicPorts = myLogicPorts
  convert x = return $ x > 0

-- All this work to write:
testMyBlock :: State MyBlock Bool
testMyBlock = runLogic
```

It results in the following error:

```
Typed.hs:39:7:
    Could not deduce (block ~ Block state1 ports1)
    from the context (LogicBlock block incoming outgoing)
      bound by the class declaration for `LogicBlock'
      at Typed.hs:(27,1)-(41,19)
      `block' is a rigid type variable bound by
              the class declaration for `LogicBlock' at Typed.hs:26:18
    Expected type: StateT block Data.Functor.Identity.Identity outgoing
      Actual type: State (Block state1 ports1) outgoing
    In the return type of a call of `convert'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: convert inputMessage
```

And here is the failing "vtable" code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module VTable where

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Lens.Lazy
import Data.Lens.Template

-- Generic Block.
data Block state ports = Block { _blockState :: state, _blockPorts :: ports }

-- For the logic we want to use, we need some state and ports.
data LogicState = LogicState { _field :: Bool }
data LogicPorts incoming outgoing =
  LogicPorts { _input :: incoming, _output :: outgoing }

makeLenses [ ''Block, ''LogicState, ''LogicPorts ]

-- We need to describe how to reach the needed state and ports,
-- and provide a piece of the logic.
data BlockLogic block incoming outgoing where
  BlockLogic :: { logicState :: Lens state LogicState
                , logicPorts :: Lens ports (LogicPorts incoming outgoing)
                , convert :: incoming -> State block outgoing
                }
             -> BlockLogic (Block state ports) incoming outgoing

-- | The generic piece of logic.
runLogic :: forall block state ports incoming outgoing
          . block ~ Block state ports
         => BlockLogic block incoming outgoing
         -> State block outgoing
runLogic BlockLogic { .. } = do
  state <- access $ blockState
  let myField = state ^. logicState ^. field
  if myField
  then do
    ports <- access blockPorts
    let inputMessage = ports ^. logicPorts ^. input
    convert inputMessage
  else
    error "Sorry"

-- My block uses the generic logic, and also maintains additional state and ports.
data MyState = MyState { _myLogicState :: LogicState, _myMoreState :: Bool }
data MyPorts = MyPorts { _myLogicPorts :: LogicPorts Int Bool, _myMorePorts :: Int }

makeLenses [ ''MyState, ''MyPorts ]

type MyBlock = Block MyState MyPorts

-- All this work to write:
testMyBlock :: State MyBlock Bool
testMyBlock = runLogic $ BlockLogic
                         { logicState = myLogicState
                         , logicPorts = myLogicPorts
                         , convert = \x -> return $ x > 0
                         }
```

It results in the following error:

```
VTable.hs:44:5:
    Could not deduce (block1 ~ Block state1 ports1)
    from the context (block ~ Block state ports)
      bound by the type signature for
                 runLogic :: block ~ Block state ports =>
                             BlockLogic block incoming outgoing -> State block outgoing
      at VTable.hs:(37,1)-(46,17)
    or from (block ~ Block state1 ports1)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 BlockLogic :: forall incoming outgoing state ports block.
                               Lens state LogicState
                               -> Lens ports (LogicPorts incoming outgoing)
                               -> (incoming -> State block outgoing)
                               -> BlockLogic (Block state ports) incoming outgoing,
               in an equation for `runLogic'
      at VTable.hs:37:10-26
      `block1' is a rigid type variable bound by
               a pattern with constructor
                 BlockLogic :: forall incoming outgoing state ports block.
                               Lens state LogicState
                               -> Lens ports (LogicPorts incoming outgoing)
                               -> (incoming -> State block outgoing)
                               -> BlockLogic (Block state ports) incoming outgoing,
               in an equation for `runLogic'
               at VTable.hs:37:10
    Expected type: block1
      Actual type: block
    Expected type: StateT
                     block1 Data.Functor.Identity.Identity outgoing
      Actual type: State block outgoing
    In the return type of a call of `convert'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: convert inputMessage
```

I don't get why GHC is going for "block1" when the whole thing is explicitly under ScopedTypeVariables and "forall block".

Edit #1: Added functional dependencies, thanks to Chris Kuklewicz for pointing this out. The problem remains though.

Edit #2: As Chris pointed out, in the VTable solution, getting rid of all the "block ~ Block state ports" and instead writing "Block state ports" everywhere solves the problem.

Edit #3: Ok, so the problem seems to be that for each and every separate function, GHC requires sufficient type information in the parameters to deduce *all* the types, even for types that aren't used at all. So in the case of (for example) logicState above, the parameters only give us the state, which isn't enough to know what the ports and incoming and outgoing types are. Never mind it doesn't really matter to the logicState function; GHC wants to know, and can't, so compilation fails. If this is indeed the core reason, it would have been better if GHC complained directly when compiling the logicState decleration - it seems it has enough information to detect a problem there; if I had seen a problem saying "ports type is not used/determined" at that location, it would have been much clearer.

Edit #4: It still isn't clear to me why (block ~ Block state ports) doesn't work; I guess I'm using it for an unintended purpose? It seems like it should have worked. I agree with Chris that using CPP to work around it is an abomination; but writing "B t r p e" (in my real code that has more paraneters) isn't a good solution either.

Comment: The type class solution is broken: calls to runLogic do not provide the incoming type, same for logicState.

Comment: I don'y follow what you mean by "calls to runLogic do not provide the incoming type". I thought I specified the incoming type when I did "instance MyBlock ...".

Comment: At the call site, "runLogic :: State block outgoing" might be inferred from context or specified by a type annotation, but what if there are "instance LogicBlock block inAlpha outgoing" and "instance LogicBlock block inBeta outgoing" ?? Which instance should runLogic dispatch to ??

Comment: Right, my bad. This is where FunDeps would go in. block -> incoming, block -> outgoing. The compilation error remains, though :-(

Comment: I have added a PPS to my answer to discuss those remaining errors.

Comment: Since you have functional dependencies, the new Type families may be able to replaces some of "B t r p e" noise.

Comment: "Never mind it doesn't really matter to the logicState function;" is false for the type class solution.  GHC needs enough to parameters so it can use the functional dependencies to pick your instance. Imagine an opponent declares a similar instance that differs in the unmentioned parameters -- there are now two logicState that match your request!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a one line fix for your VTable code:

```
            , convert :: incoming -> State block outgoing
```

becomes

```
            , convert :: incoming -> State (Block state ports) outgoing
```

Then you should simplify the type of `runLogic` to

```
runLogic :: BlockLogic (Block state ports) incoming outgoing
         -> State (Block state ports) outgoing
```

PS: More detail to answer comments below.

Eliminating "block ~" was not part of the fix.  Usually "~" is only needed in `instance a~b => ... where` situations.

Previously if I give a function a `xxx :: BlockLogic (Block state ports) incoming outgoing` then it can unpack `convert xxx :: State block outgoing`.  But the new `block` is not at all related to `(Block state ports)`, it is a new unknowable type.  The compiler append a digit to the end of the name to make `block1` which then appears in the error messages.

The original code (both versions) have problems with what types the compiler can infer from a given context.

As for verbosity, try `type`.  Do not use CPP and DEFINE.

```
type B s p = BlockLogic (Block s p)

runLogic :: B s p i o -> State (Block s p) o
```

PPS: Further explanation of problems with class version.  If I substitute (Block s p) for block and add the functional dependencies you mentioned:

```
class LogicBlock state ports incoming outgoing | state ports -> incoming outgoing where
  logicState :: Lens state LogicState
  logicPorts :: Lens ports (LogicPorts incoming outgoing)
  convert :: incoming -> State (Block state ports) outgoing
```

Using logicState nails down `state` but leaves `ports` unknown, making `ports#`

Using logicPorts nails down `ports` but leaves `state` unknown, making `ports#`

Compiling `runLogic` runs into lots of type mismatch errors between ports, ports0, ports1 and state, state0, state1.

These operations do not seem to fit together into the same type class.  You could break them out into separate type classes, or perhaps add ", state->ports, ports->state" functional dependencies to the class declaration.

Comment: Yes, I discovered this; but this is a boiled-down version of my real code. In my real code, it is "Block structure state ports events", not "Block state ports", so repeating it everywhere is that much more painful. So, as a workaround, this is an OK solution (I can always #define BLOCK Block structure state ports events :-). But the question still stands. Why doesn't this compile as it stands? Why should eliminating the block ~ ... make a difference? Is this a GHC bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I added the PS to my answer above to respond to your questions.

Comment: I kind of see what you are saying; each function needs to have concrete arguments sufficient to nail down enough "independent" types required to deduce _all_ the "dependent" types. So in the case of logicState, GHC still feels obliged to know what ports and incoming and outgoing are, even though the function doesn't need them at all; and since there isn't enough information on the arguments to determine them, the compilation fails. I guess that makes sense, but I'd expect GHC to complain when compiling logicState - that would have been much clearer. Splitting to several typeclasses may help.

Comment: You said "eliminating block ~ wasn't part of the fix". However, this _was_ the fix, for the VTable case anyway. I don't like using CPP, but I also don't like saying stuff like "B r t p e i o" all over the place. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: "eliminating block ~ wasn't part of the fix" is true of the "~" that was being used in type of runLogic.  You could even put it back.

Comment: True, but I can't do this in the definition of, say, "convert". Typically I have several "convert"-like function fields that need the combined type, and only one (or two) "runLogic"-like functions that are able to use "block ~". BTW, is there a simple explanation as to why "block ~" doesn't work? Is it simply a GHC implementation limitation?